# Remove all letters from a variable except the period?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am doing some webscraping and trying to filter this variable.

```js
var oldtext = $0.00Amount

var newtext= text.replace(/\D/g, "");
```

This results in '000' and I need to keep the period.

I know I could write a replace function for each $, A, M, O, U, N, T but is there a smarter way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log("Price is 1.223$".replace(/[^\d.]/g, ""))
```

Comment: Thank you that worked!

Answer (score 0):

it covers negative values also.

```js
console.log("Price is 1.223$".replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
```